# Why can't I download DLC in the background anymore?

Tags: xbox-360

I've been having this unusual issue lately with my Xbox and certain bits of DLC.

Typically when I start to download something, I can press B or the Guide button to send the download to the background, and then I can check on the status of the download and the queued downloads by using the "Active Downloads" entry on the Guide.

However, when I download DLC from in-game menus, if I back out while it is downloading the download seems to abort.  The "Active Downloads" screen is blank, and if I go into the "Storage" view, it says the download is "Incomplete."  I've been able to complete the download if I leave the Xbox turned on and don't back out of the initial status screen you get when you initiate the download, but this is inconvenient and irritating.

It seems to happen exclusively with DLC that is downloaded in-game, for instance, Borderlands 2 DLC with the Season Pass, and the Halo 4 Crimson Map Pack.  Both of these aren't downloaded through the Live Marketplace, and must be chosen from in-game menus.  I don't remember this issue when I was playing LA Noire, though (and I had a Season Pass for that game).  I can also download or re-download items directly from the Marketplace and they end up in the "active downloads" menu with no issues.

What gives?  Is there a setting I need to change, or something I can reset to get this functionality back for in-game DLC?

Comment: Not a fix or an explanation, but I did discover that you can work around this by attempting the download, backing out, and going to the Guide.  Then, go all the way to the right and pick "Account Management" then "Download History" and download the DLC from this menu.

Answer (score 3):

When downloading DLC from a menu initiated inside of a game, you can't background download it. What you can do for the larger ones is you can quit to the dashboard, go to your download history in your account, and choose it there again to download. Now you can download your DLC in the background and play something else in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is just how some downloads work.

When downloading in-game DLC that is part of a season pass, it uses a slightly different download mechanism that cancels the download when you exit the screen.

The only way around this is to download it again from your download history, as @agent86 said in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

With a lot of multiplayer intensive games such as Call of Duty on the Xbox; Background downloading is often disabled to stop people from lagging matches out or intentionally "standbying" regardless of whether you're actually playing online or not is supposedly the reasoning behind it. A tad over-reaching i know but it's the best of a bad situation